# Inserting Image into Table class properly

Tags: html

I need help adding my Code into a table that is in a class called "placeholder"
It's a box of squares and i need to add an image into it.

I tried

```
                    <caption align="bottom" class="placeholder">My Text</caption>
                    <td><img src="my image"/></td>
```

and it goes into a table box well but is no where near where it's supposed it. I also want to make it where you can hover over it shows the text

Heres an example on how it looks... sorry if part of it is cut off. https://gyazo.com/5e63b5a1fb7b48111ec012f8c6c725c0

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put an image in the element with `class="placeholder"`?
Then either use css:

```
.placeholder {
    background-image: url("yourURL.jpg");
}
```

Note, that this adds an image to every element with `class="placeholder"`.
If you want to do it with html, just use `<img src="yourURL.jpg">` and put it whereever you need the image.

Comment: It's not working... I have the Code shown in a GIF and where it's supposed to be shown... The above code didn't show nothing so i changed it and still nothing... https://gyazo.com/06ab56a4596c10c66606880f5126693b

Comment: Update : I added <img src="yourURL.jpg"> as you said and it shows up now but just incorrectly.. https://gyazo.com/bc9e46b03d6442072d83a9b9572cdca3

Comment: now I know what you wanted to do. you have to put the `<img>` tag INSIDE the `<div>` tag. Like so:
`<div class="placeholder"><img src="URL"></div>`

Comment: Thanks it's looking better... however it is barely off it's in the right spot just needs to be up a little... i wonder why. It's not the image size i tried default 110x110 and even 90x90... https://gyazo.com/4daa276072d351d204f1afe6cd608c51

Comment: Nevermind... That you for your help i found the fix. I just need to repeat the code on the rest of the values so they all move right next to it. I appreciate it.